# How to open a modal component through an onClick from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This question is related [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70772221/onmouseenter-generates-is-not-a-function-error-when-trying-to-set-the-value-of). I am rewording to make it simple.

I have a main navigation component (MainNavigation.js) which is siblings with a Secondary Navigation Component(SecNavigation.js) under the Header component(Header.js).

What I want is when I click on a specific Link in the MainNavigation.js the whole SecNavigation.js to be displayed in a modal.

My problem here is that I don't quite grasp how should I go using useState, useContext or even if I need any of this.

Comment: Using the React Context API seems a solid approach. Are you basically asking the same question as your other post, or asking for a different approach?

Comment: I am actually asking for a different approach. Based on the traction of the previous question got I guessed I must be doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: Nope, not at all, lifting state up to a common ancestor is a starting point, but eventually you get to centralizing state in a Context.

Comment: Let me create a codeSandbox for you and try to explain it. Hold on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will clear something for you

What you need is a parent that handles the state and then it will pass it down to its children. Because the parent is keeping track of the children and what they are doing.

So what I have done it this:

App.js is the parent and I handle the state here.
Then I just pass down the `setIsModalShowing` setState function to the MainNav that will call it when I press a button.

Then in the App.js I will show or hide the modal if the `setIsModalShowing` is `true` or `false`

inside of the modal I am showing `SecNav` and the modal also has the  `setIsModalShowing` passed down so that you can click on the button to close is and that will set the state to false.

Does that makes sense to you ? or else I can try to explain it in another way

[Code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-fire-fv4id?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: You just need to change the onClick to onMouseEnter to trigger when the mouse pointer is hover that component if you want that side effect

Comment: I appreciate your answer. It really clears things up. The problem I was having with my previous related question was simple. I was not passing setOpenModal down the MainNavigation component. I will use this approach instead of Context for now.

Comment: no problem, if there is something that you get stuck on just write here and we can look at it